# Filter not functioning, need only the tags whose child match a selector

Tags: jquery-selectors

given the html:

```
<div class="ships">
  <div class="ship header">
  </div>
  <div class="ship">
    <div class="image">
      <img alt="Hermes_class" src="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="number">x10</div>
  </div>
 ... //other ships
```

I want only the number text of the ship matching img alt="Hermes_class".

Here's where I start:

```
var finalShipListDom = $jq('div.ship:not(.header)', finalCombatantShips);
             if(finalShipListDom.length<=0)
                 console.log("fsld="+finalShipListDom.length);
```

i've tried all these to get the ship dom so I could go down from there to get the number.

```
$jq('div.ship',finalShipListDom).filter('div.image img[alt="' +shipClass + '"]');
```

and

```
 var finalShipDomFilter= function(index){
               return jQuery('div.image',this).length>=1;
             }
```

and

```
     var finalShipDomFilter= function(index){
               return jQuery('div div.image',this).length>=1;
             }
```

all are returning 0 length.

There's a debug bin/live example available at http://jsbin.com/alebi3/9/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [jQuery.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/). Something like this should get you the div that contains the div `<div class="number">x10</div>`:

```
$jq('div.ship:not(.header)', finalCombatantShips)
    .has('div.number > img[alt=' + shipClass + ']');
```

N.B. you do not need to insert quotes into the attribute value in the selector.

Comment: reading the description of `.has()` it sounds like what I'm looking for, about to try it.